# Is there a centralized archive of ballot design samples from around the world?

Tags: election, ballot

I'm kind of an election nerd looking for a place to view different ballot designs from around the world.

For instance, I'm happy to have found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xr16hqxqAT8) from International IDEA analysing ballot designs from Nordic countries. But it's just a video and not an exhaustive list of ballot samples globally.

Was hoping there would be a WIkipedia page for this, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: This might be your chance to create one, if there isn't yet one.

Comment: Such a collection would be a massive undertaking if were to catalog ballot designs from all countries. It would have to collect examples of ballots for lower & upper houses of government (congress & senate) where they exist for both national & state/provincial governments. Would you want it to also include designs for referenda questions and for municipal/council elections for local government?

Comment: @Fred I think national election is enough. I'm just interested in how different countries implement their ballot design, especially in places that use open-list system.